# Use of UIViewController for UITableView tableHeaderView

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, uitableview

My question is mostly architectural in nature. I am using a `UITableViewController` to display a list of stuff. No big deal, pretty standard. However, the `tableHeaderView` contains a significant amount of functionality. There are a few tap targets, it animates, and the display changes based on user interaction. Currently I have a custom subclassed `UIView` handling most of the display logic and routing taps back through a delegate protocol to the `UITableViewController` for execution.

As more functionality gets added to the `tableHeaderView`, I feel as though my `UITableViewController` is becoming a bit cluttered and long. Thus I am curious if it makes sense to create a subclassed `UIViewContoller` and set its `view` to the `tableHeaderView` of my `UITableViewController`? If this is done, I would separate concerns a bit more and could house almost all of the logic in my new `UIViewController' I am guessing I would still need to route some communication via a delegate between the two viewControllers.

Does this make sense from an architectural perspective? Or should I just continue using the existing `UITableViewController` for all logic?

** EDIT **

For example, does this code make sense when placed in my `UITableViewController`

```
- (void)addHeader
{
    myCustomHeaderViewController *hvc = [[myCustomHeaderViewController alloc] init];
    //Assume the view for hvc is set up w/re to sizing, etc.
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = hvc.view
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, starting in iOS5 you have Containment View Controllers, so in one view controller you can add several child view controllers that will work together.

You can add your header view as a UIViewController and your table view as a UITableViewController in separate view controllers like this:

```
- (void) addViewController: (UIViewController*)content;
{
   [self addChildViewController:content];                 
   content.view.frame = [self frameForController];
   [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
}
```

Here you can find a guide of how you can use them:

[Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6)

Comment: Thanks for responding. Not sure I totally understand. Considering the example code I just posted, is view controller containment still required? Assume my UITableViewController is the "master" in this scenario.

Comment: I see. Does this create any performance concerns? By creating the table in whole and then using the master UIScrollViewController to hand scrolling down through cells, do I miss out on the cell queuing from the UITableViewController? Seems like the frame of the UIScrollViewController would be rather large, as opposed to the UITableViewController having a small frame and queuing cells to be displayed. Apologies if this is an uninformed question.

Comment: So are you suggesting I use view controller containment, but with my UITableViewController as the master?

Comment: That could be an approach, and use addChild to add the view controller of the header to the master and then add the view to the header

Comment: Hi, did view controller containment work with UITableViewController as "container"?